# How to open url with selenium webdriver python with differents IPs?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--proxy-server=125.62.213.229:82')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='F:\Drivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

browser.get("http://www.whatismyipaddress.com")
```

I dont know to apply loop in this.

Answer (score 0):

using .format to substitute.

```
ip=['125.62.213.229:82'] # add others here.
for i in ip:
    options.add_argument(('--proxy-server={0}').format(i))
    #rest of your code
```